# How to make this mesh 'expand' as an animation

Tags: animation, mesh, animation-nodes, masking

I have the below basic mesh (bear in mind I will eventually like to do this with more complex mesh's).

I'd like to animate it with either (or both) of the following:

- The equivalent of animating a mask in After Effects, so that the mesh is 'revealed' as the mask slides sideways
- For the mesh to expand / grow / inflate, but mainly just on the X axis only. I would just animate the scale but it wouldnt look very good on more complex objects

[image]

[image]

Comment: For the mask you can use a plane with the Holdout option on, or a Holdout node, so that it will appear completely transparent. Don't forget to enable the Render > Film > Transparent option. For the second question, you want it to expend but you say that if you scale it on X it won't look good, why wouldn't it be what you want. In both case maybe give more details on what you want to achieve, show some videos, etc